# Running PhP JavaBridge on my website hosted by godaddy

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge, java-bridge-method

I am working on a code which requires java at the back-end and php at the front end to enable users print tickets/receipt from a printer. So far, my PhP JavaBridge code is working perfectly on my xmapp/tomcat intranet server.

But when i upload this code to my domain hosted by godaddy, it shows nothing. Is there a special configuration i need to do to run JavaBridge on godaddy or on a remote server?

Comment: Considered asking GoDaddy support? I think many would agree that you should switch hosting company at once, imo it is one of the most horrible of them all.

Comment: I agree with  @RonniSkansing I have recently relinquished my godaddy membership, their default server configs are horrible, I switched over to Digital Ocean VPN, much more flexibility.

Comment: wow...I guess i will contact them asap